# Inserting database row with values from another table

Tags: mysql, select, insert-into

Basically, I have two tables: `images` and `servers`. When I want to insert a row into the `images` table, I need to specify a `s_id` as one of the fields. Problem is, I only have `name`, which is another field in the `servers` table. I need to find what `s_id` belongs to `name`, and then use that in my `INSERT INTO` query on the `images` table.

Maybe this image will help:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyMRJ.png

I only know the `name` field from the `servers` table, and I need to use it to get the `s_id` field from the `servers` table. When I have that, I can use it in my `INSERT INTO` query, as it's a foreign key.

I found this:
http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html

But it just confused me even more.

One solution would be to run two queries. One to get the `s_id`, and one to run the insert query. But I'd like to limit the amount of queries I run if there's a reasonable alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the `name` field have a unique constraint on it? If not, then you will certainly have problems with data integrity (regardless of your approach).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `INSERT ... SELECT` form, something like this (with real column names and values of course):

```
INSERT INTO images (s_id, u_id, name, filename, uploaded)
SELECT s_id, ...
FROM servers
WHERE name = 'the name'
```

I don't know where you're getting the `u_id`, `name`, `filename`, or `uploaded` column values for `images` but you can include them as literal values in the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO images (s_id, u_id, name, filename, uploaded)
SELECT s_id, 11, 'pancakes', 'pancakes.jpg', '2011-05-28 11:23:42'
FROM servers
WHERE name = 'the name'
```

This sort of thing will insert multiple values if `servers.name` is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this, but you'll need to fill in the items in <> with the values you want to insert.

```
INSERT INTO images (s_id, u_id, name, filename, uploaded)
   (SELECT s_id, <u_id>, <name>, <filename>, <uploaded>
   FROM imgstore.servers
   WHERE name = @server_name)
```

This is the syntax for SQL Server, but I think it will work with MySQL as well.

Here's an article on [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment above regarding a potential data integrity issue. I am assuming that the name field in your server table has a unique constraint placed on it.

There are a couple of ways that you can approach this `INSERT`, and I'm sure that some are better than others. I make no claim that my way is the best way, but it should work. I don't know how you're writing this query, so I'm going to use `@FieldValue` to represent the variable input. My approach is to use a subquery in your insert statement to get the data that you require.

```
INSERT INTO images (field1, field2... s_id) VALUES ('@field1val', '@field2val'... (SELECT s_id FROM servers WHERE name='@nameval'));
```